# How can I insert rows in another table using this MySQL select statement?

Tags: mysql, select

How can I use the results of this select statement to insert rows in another table?

```
SELECT "Old Town" AS neighborhoods, reportdatetime, IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(
POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , POLYFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON((38.91911 -77.03648000000001,
38.918150000000004 -77.03979000000001,
38.917910000000006 -77.0403,
38.91734 -77.04073000000001,
38.91911 -77.03648000000001
 ))' )
)AS result, latitude, longitude, sport_type
FROM sport
WHERE IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(
POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , POLYFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON((38.91911 -77.03648000000001,
38.918150000000004 -77.03979000000001,
38.917910000000006 -77.0403,
38.91734 -77.04073000000001,
38.91911 -77.03648000000001 ))' )
) = 1;
```

I'd like to put the results of this Select into a table called sports_by_neighborhood. Its structure is as follows:

- neighborhoods (varchar 50)
- result (tinyint 1)
- reportdatetime
  (datetime)
- latitude (decimal 11,9)
- longitude (decimal 10,8)
- sport_type (varchar 30)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [insert select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO other_table ( neighborhoods, reportdatetime, result, latitude, longitude, sport_type )
SELECT "Old Town" AS neighborhoods, reportdatetime, IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(
POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , POLYFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON((38.91911 -77.03648000000001,
38.918150000000004 -77.03979000000001,
38.917910000000006 -77.0403,
38.91734 -77.04073000000001,
38.91911 -77.03648000000001
 ))' )
)AS result, latitude, longitude, sport_type
FROM sport
WHERE IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(
POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , POLYFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON((38.91911 -77.03648000000001,
38.918150000000004 -77.03979000000001,
38.917910000000006 -77.0403,
38.91734 -77.04073000000001,
38.91911 -77.03648000000001 ))' )
) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO sports_by_neighborhood (neighborhoods, reportdatetime, result, latitude,longitude, sport_type)
 SELECT "Old Town" AS neighborhoods, reportdatetime, IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(
POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , POLYFROMTEXT(     'POLYGON((38.91911 -77.03648000000001,
38.918150000000004 -77.03979000000001,
38.917910000000006 -77.0403,
38.91734 -77.04073000000001,
38.91911 -77.03648000000001
 ))' )
)AS result, latitude, longitude, sport_type
FROM sport
WHERE IS_POINT_IN_POLYGON(
POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , POLYFROMTEXT(     'POLYGON((38.91911 -77.03648000000001,
38.918150000000004 -77.03979000000001,
38.917910000000006 -77.0403,
38.91734 -77.04073000000001,
38.91911 -77.03648000000001 ))' )
) = 1;
```